# Python - Error with scikit learn Random Forest about values format

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, random-forest

When I execute the command:

```
clf.fit(train_data, train_label)
```

I'm obtaining the following error

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

The problem is the array `train_data` with size (18000,20). I've tried to use this command:

```
clf.fit(np.float32(train_data), train_label)
```

or

```
train_data = np.array([s[0].astype('float32') for s in train_data])
```

Find the datasets train_data and train_label in the train file (python) in the following link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3017gi18x6x325/train?dl=0

However, I cannot get that all the values from the array "train_data" being valid for the `clf.fit` function. Any help?

Comment: It should be because you have a wrong value (NaN or infinity) in one of the entries of your matrix... That is, your matrix is singular or you had an error on `train_data` from the beginning. If you use other train_data that does not present that it should be fine. How does your `train_data` looks?

Comment: Can you upload train_data and train_label? Maybe you have any string or NaN in train_data ??

Comment: Please, @sera find the datasets in the link added. Thanks

Comment: @Ruser sorry but how can i open this file?

Comment: @sera use:    with open('train', 'rb') as f:  
    train_data, train_label = pickle.load(f)

Comment: @Ruser still cannot open it. can you use something like: pickle.dump(your_object, your_file, protocol=0) to write the train? I use python 2.7. I guess you use python 3.x. You file is protocol 3 but python 2.x has only 0,1,2 protocols

Comment: @sera, please, try with the new file.

Comment: @Ruser the link seems broken now

Comment: @sera Check this. Sorry and Thanks  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0mp5ovtxtkjhfsj/AABtphHxHKIDCpsE48Q0-Hufa?dl=0

Comment: @Ruser please see my answer. This works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution to overcome this error. You need to scale the data:

Code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pickle
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

with open('train', 'rb') as f: 
    train_data, train_label = pickle.load(f)

#some diagnostic to see if there are NaNs. No NaN were found !
print(np.isnan(train_data))
print(np.where(np.isnan(train_data)))
print(np.nan_to_num(train_data))
print(np.isnan(train_label))
print(np.where(np.isnan(train_label)))

#so need to scale
train_data = scale(train_data)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data, train_label)
```

Comment: Thank you @sera, it worked. However, since I'm splitting the dataset for cross-validation, one specific dataset doesn't work. Can you check it? Thanks again. https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1hl5zs0chkthc6/train?dl=0 (link checked)

Comment: @Ruser  yes I will check it! What CV do you use ? Leave one out ? K folds ?

Comment: Find the whole @sera script in File and the new dataset in "data".  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0mp5ovtxtkjhfsj/AABtphHxHKIDCpsE48Q0-Hufa?dl=0

Comment: @Ruser how can i open your script?

Comment: Please, check https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0mp5ovtxtkjhfsj/AABtphHxHKIDCpsE48Q0-Hufa?dl=0 (I didn't add the .py extension)

Comment: @Ruser as i can see in your script, you import the scale but you do not use it !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148601/discussion-between-sera-and-r-user).

Comment: I didn't added the scale in this file (sorry) , but adding it still fails. Thanks. Can you try?